# Spark: Option in mapPartition throwing Task not serializable

Tags: scala, apache-spark, serialization, apache-spark-sql

The following is blowing spark with `Task not serializable`.

```scala
    val mergedDF: Dataset[String] = readyToMergeDF
      .mapPartitions((rows: Iterator[Row]) =>
        mergePayloads(rows, Some(schemaForDataValidation.value))
      )
```

But **without passing the option** it is working fine:

```scala
    val mergedDF: Dataset[String] = readyToMergeDF
      .mapPartitions((rows: Iterator[Row]) =>
        mergePayloads(rows)
      )
```

Where `schemaForDataValidation` is a broadcasted Map (tried without broadcasting - yields the same error):

```scala
  lazy val schemaForDataValidation: Broadcast[Map[String, Map[String, Any]]] = getSchemaForValidation
```

And `mergePayloads` has the following signature placed in another Object (that extends `Serializable`) :

```scala
object UpdateTableMethods extends Logging with Serializable {

  def mergePayloads(iterator: Iterator[Row], schemaOpt: Option[Map[String, Map[String, Any]]] = None): Iterator[String]
```

I checked the `Option` class source code. `Some` is a case class - therefore is serializable and `Option` itself extends `Serializable`.
Actually, I have also tried not passing the parameter as an option, but a Map that can be empty/null.

Appreciate your help.

Thank you all.

Comment: `Any` in the map is smelly

Comment: Tried with String also. Didnt work too.

Comment: I might be stating the obvious but when calling `mapPartitions` values and functions passed to it must be serialized for transfer to executors and  `Iterator` is absolutely not serializable. Use `List` or a `Seq` instead ?

Comment: You might be right , but the iterator here is just part of mapPartitions lamnda signature. I am not passing it further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem: inject the variable in a serizable class with the method that uses it.

```scala
val merger = PayloadsMerger(schemaForDataValidationBroadcast.value)

val mergedDF: Dataset[String] = readyToMergeDF
  .mapPartitions((rows: Iterator[Row]) =>
    merger.merge(rows)
  )
```

Where `PayloadsMerger` carries the variable and method:

```scala
case class PayloadsMerger(expectedSchema: Option[Map[String, Map[String, Any]]]) {

  def merge(iterator: Iterator[Row]): Iterator[String] = {
    PayloadsMerger.mergePayloads(iterator, expectedSchema)
  }

}
```

Using this kind of clousure technique enables serialization, since scala case classes mixin `serializable` [trait](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.14/index.html#scala.Serializable).